# String number range treatment in Java

Tags: java, string, range

I have a String value

```
strValue1 = “-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-“;
```

and

```
strValue2 = “-4-5-6-7-“;
```

I want to get from **strValue1** only the range I have in **strValue2**.

Which should be **-4-5-6-7-**

Could you help on this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by _get_? Do you mean you want to check if the first contains the second?

Comment: Where is your code ? What would be your input and output ?

Comment: I don't get the question. Why would you want to get the range from s1 when you already have it in s2?

Comment: please explain the expected output in your case

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis 
Thanks for your answer, I don’t need to check, str2 is a dynamic value, when it arrives, I have to get (copy) the exact value from str1.

Comment: @Rehman: 
Thanks for your reply, I asked for an example, I don’t have a code yet. Input value is str2 which is dynamic; the str1 is a static value (hardcoded).

Comment: @AbtPst:
Thanks for the reply; the expected output is a value from str1 which will be given from str2.
Let’s say str3 will have a value copied from str1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use indexOf:

```
int location = strValue1.indexOf(strValue2);
```

which will return the location of the start, or -1 if it didn't find anything.
The range would be given by (location, strValue2.length)